# Google Finance recognizes my Python script as a bot and blocks it

Tags: python, bots, google-finance

I wrote a script that retrieves stock data on google finance and prints it out, nice and simple. It always worked, but since this morning I only get a page that tells me that I'm probably an automated script instead of the stock data. Of course, being a script, I can't pass the captcha. What can I do?

Comment: You are not allowed to do this because of the ToS. Any workaround might not be legal. You can use the Google Finance API, but it will be removed in October. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api) is a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

well, you finally reached a quite challenging realm. decode the captcha.
there do exist OCR approaches to decode simple captcha into code. not seems to work for google captcha. 
I heard there are some companies provide manual captcha decoding services, you can try to use some. ^_^  LOL

ok, to be serious, if google don't want you to do it that way, then it is not easy to decode those captchas. After all, why google on finance data, there are a lot other providers, right? try to scrape those websites.

Comment: I'm gonna try and switch to yahoo finance. Unluckily google's API is scheduled for shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve the blocking issue by adding `headers` where your [user-agent](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/) will be specified, this is necessary for Google to recognize the request as from a user, and not as from a bot, and not block it:

```py
# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
```

An additional step could be to [rotate user-agents](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents):

```py
import requests, random

user_agent_list = [
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
]

for _ in user_agent_list:
  #Pick a random user agent
  user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)

  #Set the headers 
  headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

In addition to the rotate `user-agent`, you can [rotate proxies](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#proxies) (ideally residential) that can be used in combination with CAPTCHA solver to bypass CAPTCHA.

To parse dynamic websites using web browser automation, you can use [`curl-impersonate`](https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate) or [`selenium-stealth`](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth) which can bypass most CAPTCHAs, but the option using browser automation could be CPU, RAM expensive and could be difficult to run in parallel.

There's a [reducing the chance of being blocked while web scraping](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/) blog post if you need a little bit more info.

---

As an alternative you can use [Google Finance Markets API](https://serpapi.com/google-finance-markets) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Example of SerpApi code for extracting `Most Active` on the main page of Google Finance in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-finance-without-blocks-serpapi#main.py).

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import json, os

params = {
  "engine": "google_finance_markets",  # serpapi parser engine. Or engine to parse ticker page: https://serpapi.com/google-finance-api
  "trend": "most-active",              # parameter is used for retrieving different market trends: https://serpapi.com/google-finance-markets#api-parameters-search-query-trend
  "api_key": "..."                     # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
}

market_trends_data = []
search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

most_active = results["markets"]

print(json.dumps(most_active, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
      "stock": ".DJI:INDEXDJX",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/finance/quote/.DJI:INDEXDJX",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_finance&hl=en&q=.DJI%3AINDEXDJX",
      "name": "Dow Jones",
      "price": 34089.27,
      "price_movement": {
        "percentage": 0.4574563,
        "value": 156.66016,
        "movement": "Down"
      }
    },
    {
      "stock": ".INX:INDEXSP",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/finance/quote/.INX:INDEXSP",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_finance&hl=en&q=.INX%3AINDEXSP",
      "name": "S&P 500",
      "price": 4136.13,
      "price_movement": {
        "percentage": 0.028041454,
        "value": 1.1601563,
        "movement": "Down"
      }
    },
    other results ...
]
```